# Doctrine2 Second level cache only working with ID and no associations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

So, we have two entities

`Product` and `Brand`.

```
AppBundle\Entity\Brand:
    type: entity
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    cache:
        usage : READ_ONLY
        region : region_products
    oneToMany:
        products:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Product
            mappedBy: brand
            cache:
                usage : READ_ONLY
            cascade: ["remove", "persist"]
            orderBy: { 'name': 'ASC' }


AppBundle\Entity\Product:
    type: entity
    cache:
        usage : READ_ONLY
        region : region_products
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO

    manyToOne:
        brand:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Brand
            inversedBy: products
            joinColumns:
                brand_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            cache:
                usage : READ_ONLY
```

We have configured Doctrine2 2lc with Redis

```
services:
    snc_second_level_cache:
        class: "%snc_redis.doctrine_cache_phpredis.class%"
        calls:
            - ["setRedis", ["@snc_redis.second_level_cache"]]
            - ["setNamespace", ["slc_"]]

doctrine:
    orm:
        result_cache_driver: redis
        metadata_cache_driver: redis
        query_cache_driver: redis
        second_level_cache:
            region_cache_driver:
                type: service
                id: snc_second_level_cache
            region_lock_lifetime: 60
            log_enabled: true
            region_lifetime: 300
            enabled: true
            regions:
                region_products:
                    cache_driver:
                        type: service
                        id: snc_second_level_cache
                    lifetime: 300
```

And what we want to do is caching every `Brand` and it's related `Product`, so if we retrieve a `Brand` in cache, it gives us it's `Product` too.

Following Doctrine's documentation, we ended up with the above config and this query.

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$result = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Brand')->findAll();
```

This actually puts all our brands into Redis, if we do the query again, is not triggered in MySQL but Redis instead, which is OK.

But there are some cases in where we don't understand what is going on

1. Using `->find($id)` hits the cache and retrieve our `Brand` from
   Redis, but using `->findOneBy(array('name' => 'foo'));` is not
   fetching from Redis, it makes a MySQL query, and then caches both,
   query and result into Redis, then, the second time you perform that
   query, you get `foo` brand from Redis. If 2lc is caching the entire
   entity, why doesn't it try to find into `name` field? Which is
   actually in Redis!.
2. Using `$result->getProducts()` makes a MySQL
   query, and caches the resulting entities, isn't it supossed to be
   already in Redis, as we have configured that way? (with cache in the
   YAML annotation into the association mapping)

Answer (score 0):

You are using Redis but it could be another cache engine (or be in file). What is cache is a serialization of the result as a key/value. It's not using the Redis NoSQL system to be able to query a structured object in redis if it's what you are looking for.

What you have in the cache is a key value of the serialization of the result as atomic as possible. So in a sql query you have all the primary key and on then all the object of the query are fetch individually in the cache. So if you update one of your brand it doesn't need to invalidate all the cache related to it but only the entry that contain the brand it self.

For you Brand->products it's the same thing, the products cache entry is a collection that contain just the id for the product, first time you call the getProducts will trigger a query, second time it will not.